# References not appear when Org converting to docx with pandoc

Tags: pandoc

Is there a way to keep the references when converting an Org mode doc to a word document using pandoc?

Comment: could you clarify what you mean by references?

Comment: I am creating an Org file with references using natbib, and then I convert it to a word document, it works well but there are no references in text nor bibliography section at the end of the file generated with pandoc.

Comment: That isn't still enough information. Do you use \cite{key} or cite:key from org-ref? I guess you should export to Latex, and then use pandoc to go from Latex to Word.

Comment: Yes I tried to convert both the org file and the tex file. I am using cite:key org ref style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2015/06/11/ox-pandoc-org-mode-+-org-ref-to-docx-with-bibliographies/ or http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2015/01/29/Export-org-mode-to-docx-with-citations-via-pandoc/ They both have examples of citations that make it through to word documents.

Comment: I followed the first link and it works. I just lost the cite:key_ref style which I preferred it better than the LaTeX \cite{} way.

Comment: Links to your own work or products without disclosure are considered spam, and answers should be more than just links to outside sources